# Why don't threads run consistently?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I am playing around with multithreading and came across an inconsistency when running a small snippet of code. The following code should print out 123123... but what I'm getting is

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
    private String message;

    RunnableDemo(String m) {
        message = m;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        new Thread(new RunnableDemo("1111111")).start();
        new Thread(new RunnableDemo("2222222")).start();
        new Thread(new RunnableDemo("3333333")).start();

    }
}
```

> Output: 123231231132123231321
>
> Output: 123213123123213213213
>
> Output: 123231213213231231213

What I don't get is that it run correctly the first pass through (prints '123') but then the second pass through it prints '231'. If the thread is printing a char, sleeping 1 second, then repeating. Shouldn't the pattern 123123... be consistent each time I run the code or at least follow the pattern of the first 3 chars?

Comment: They're threads, you're not scheduling them, the JVM/OS is. Also, stock Java isn't real-time; trivial differences in sleep counting and switching will alter results.

Comment: To add to @DaveNewton 's comment, you will have to ensure that the 3 threads execute one after another by using `synchronization` or a lock

Comment: I can translate this question to: "Why when I make stuff run in parallel does it not happen in sequence?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The following code should print out 123123

Not necessarily. You should basically *never* rely on threads with no synchronization between them happening to wake up and execute in any particular order.

Let's take the *very first* character output: there's no guarantee that that will be 1. Yes, you're starting the thread printing 1 first, but that doesn't mean that's the first thread that will actually start executing `run` first - or even if it does, that doesn't mean that's the first thread that will get as far as the `System.out.print` call.

Given the fairly long sleep, I *would* expect (but ideally not rely on) the output being a sequence of 7 "chunks", where each "chunk" consists of the characters "123" in some permutation. But if you've got three threads which all go to sleep for a second at "roughly" the same time, you shouldn't expect them to necessarily wake up in the order 1, 2, 3 - and again, even if they do, one of them may pre-empt another within the loop body.

On a really, really slow machine, even that expectation would be invalid - imagine it takes a random amount of time between 0 and 20 seconds to call `charAt` - unlikely, but it's a *feasible* thought experiment. At that point, one of the threads could race ahead and finish its output before another of the threads managed to print *anything*.

Threads are designed to be independent - if you want them to work in a coordinated fashion, you have to specify that coordination yourself. There are plenty of tools for the job, but don't expect it to happen magically.

Comment: I like the thought experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't predict what piece of program CPU runs at a time. While running some process the CPU converts the process into small pieces of `work`. As multiple processes are running at a time. CPU has to schedule according to `scheduling algorithm` implemented. So, in short, you cannot predict what CPU does next unless you programmatically synchronize the pieces of code.